# How to pass user defined objects to REST service from angularjs

Tags: java, rest, angularjs

I am fairly new to Anuglar JS so please keep that in mind while answering this question. My goal here is to create and persist a new user in the oracle database. My frontend is written in AngularJS. A REST service (using JERSEY) is in place already with a method signature like below:

```
 @POST
 @Path("/create/{user}")
 public void createUser(@QueryParam("user") User user){ ...}
```

AngularJS Factory with REST call looks like this:

```
angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('User', function($resource) 
 {
   return 
   {
        createUser: $resource('/myurl/create/:user', {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {user: '@user'},
                isArray: false
            }
        })
   });
```

User.java has the following attributes:

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
```

I believe the above factory is set up correctly. I have verified that the backend REST service for create user also works correctly. The frontend has a form that lets a user enter FirstName, LastName and Email which should be part of the User object. I think the User object should be submitted to the Rest service via something like:

Step1: make an object with user's data
Step2: User.createUser.query(user:)

I am not sure if the steps are right and if they are then how exactly to make the object. Can someone please provide some guidelines. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resources should reflect the object not the action, your resource should be called "user". Creating, updating, querying is reflected in the http methods.

I'd implement it something like this. A large portion of this is lifted straight from the docs - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

```
angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])

.controller('MyController', function(User) {

    // Query userID 123, change the firstname and lastname then save.
    var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {
      user.firstname = "joe";
      user.lastname = "bloggs";
      user.$save();
    }

   // Create a new user like this.
   var anotherUser = new User({
     username: 'joe.bloggs',
     email: 'joe.bloggs@example.com',
     firstname: 'joe',
     lastname: 'bloggs'
   });

   anotheruser.$save();
 })    

.factory('User', function($resource) 
 {       
    // Represent the user resource.
    return $resource('/myurl/create/:userId', {userId:'@id'});    

 });
```

Comment: I have seen this before and I don't understand how you can say User.get({userId:123}... where is get and $save defined? sorry, I am sure this is a newbie question. Thank you though.

Comment: that's the interface into the resource representation that $resource returns. You can get, post, put, remove from that.

Comment: I've just updated the example to include creating a new resource. A resource isn't an action, it's a data set that you can perform actions on (sorry if you know this already). For example:

POST to /user -> creates a new user, and should return me a representation of my new user (including ID).

GET to /user/123 -> Returns you the data set for your user, similar to what you got back after your POST.

PUT to /user/123 -> Amends any data you have in your user data set. Should return something similar to GET. The key is that it's all the "User" resource. $resource is trying to show that.

Comment: I really appreciate that explanation! I noticed that your return statement is the $resource stmt itself. In my post I have return { createUser: .... }. The reason I had it this way is so that I can have various rest endpoints (getUserById, getUserBySsn, etc) mapped to the same User factory. How can I do that in your example? Still trying to learn how this magic happens..

Comment: you have an endpoint for each of those, this is part of how REST differs from normal APIs. Creating a search is different. Do a GET on /user/123 to load a user by its ID, but if you want to do a search you should do a GET on /user?ssn=1234567. $resource notices any data that isn't in a placeholder (:userID) and will append to the query string. So User.get({ssn: 1234567}) will make a GET request to /user?ssn=1234567

Comment: in case of saving a new user. what would the rest endpoint look like? Is it just @POST public User create(User auser){...}

Comment: also, the line  var anotherUser = new User({  gives me object is not a function error.

Comment: You should post straight to /user. Probably worth checking the docs for the correct syntax when using "new". When I'm back at my PC I can check it properly.

Comment: Looking at the docs that looks about right, try checking your syntax. Consult http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource for more info, and search for "new CreditCard" to see the example. If you're happy with my answer could you please mark it as correct.

Comment: eddiec do you know of any site that hosts a full example (backend and frontend) of the $resource code. I have tried all kinds of options at this point but I just can't get resources to work! POST/PUT specifically

Answer (score 0):

The QueryParam are commonly used with GET methods to send single attributes, Try this :

In your java code

```
 @POST
 @Path("/create/")
 public void createUser(User user){ ...}
```

In your js code

```
angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('User', function($resource){

    var user = $resource('/myurl/create/', {}, {
      createUser: {method:'POST', params:{...}}
    });

    return user;        
});
```

You can find more information about rest in java [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-resteasy-client-framework/) and [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html_single/#Using__Path_and__GET___POST__etc.), about angular resources [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).